# In Excel, add 1 if not number, or else add the number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In [excel](/questions/tagged/excel), how do I write a formula that does the following:

In a certain cell range, if the cell contains a non-numeric entry, add one, or else add the number the cell contains.

for example

> 4
>     xyz
>     def
>     bc
>     2
>     0

`=9`

or

> 1
>     ab
>     cd
>     2
>     af

=6

Comment: Feel free to let me know how I can better word the question, thanks!

Comment: reformatted for better clarity :)

Comment: @pnuts that was my editing, not the OP.

Comment: @pnuts, no it was my fault for bad editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contents of the data A1:A6

4
xyz
x
2
y
0

Write the following formula in cell B1

```
=SUM(A1:A6)+(COUNTA(A1:A6)-COUNT(A1:A6))
```

Comment: +1 Sakir - COUNTIF can be used to count text only so you could reduce formula to this: `=SUM(A1:A6)+COUNTIF(A1:A6,"?*")`

Comment: Hi barry. Your method is nice. Thank you. Even the ? character is not needed. I just * enough.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is write a the formula
`=ISERROR(Cell+0, 1)`
 next to each cell, and then sum across these cells.

What the formula does is it returns the value of the cell if the cell is a number, and it returns the number 1 if the operation "cell + 0" errors out (e.g. when the cell's value is not a number).

See the picture below for how i applied this to your first example.
[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I was really looking for a more elegant answer . . . unless there is no other way . . .

Answer (score 0):

I would use an array function:

```
{=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(A1:F1);A1:F1;1))}
```

Enter by writing "=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(A1:F1);A1:F1;1))" and pressing Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

```
    A | B | C | D | E | F | G
--+---+---+---+---+---+---+---
1 | 4 | a | b | c | 2 | 0 | {=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(A1:F1);A1:F1;1))}
```

Comment: seems close, but not quite right.  First, i had to change the ";" to ",", and I only get a 1 as my result . . . hmm

Comment: ";" to "," is because my computer's locale is set to Dutch. Sorry about that. The reason why you get 1 is because you probably pressed enter instead of ctrl+shift+enter.

Comment: seems like it is coming back with a 1 if there are any alpha in any of the cells.